# OpenTelemetry collector hanging in local Lambda container

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, open-telemetry

I have an AWS Lambda function which runs from a container image. I am trying to get the [AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry Lambda Support For Python](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-python) managed layer to run within my container, so that I can automatically export traces to AWS X-Ray. In order to do this, as described in [this article from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/#:%7E:text=Copy%20the%20contents%20of%20a%20Lambda%20layer%20into%20a%20container%20image), I copy the contents of the layer into the image’s `/opt` directory during `docker build`.

My configuration runs correctly on AWS; however, I have issues running my container image locally. Upon startup, I see that the collector is registered as an extension, which is correct. I invoke my Python code via a GET request, which executes my function correctly. Traces are correctly exported to the console. However, the Lambda function does not terminate, as you can see in the logs below (we see `INVOKE RTDONE` and then it waits). The container hangs until the Lambda function times out, which takes 5 minutes.

It seems like the ADOT collector/agent is continuing to run, even though my Python function has returned. **How can I get my Lambda function to end after my Python function returns?**

I got the layer contents via `curl $(aws lambda get-layer-version-by-arn --arn "arn:a ws:lambda:eu-west-3:901920570463:layer:aws-otel-python-amd64-ver-1-21-0:1")` and put them into `./otel`.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

# Copy function code
COPY ./dummy_lambda.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/dummy_lambda.py

# Copy layer code
COPY ./otel /opt/

# Copy collector config
COPY ./collector.yaml /var/task/collector.yaml

# Indicate location of collector config file
ENV OPENTELEMETRY_COLLECTOR_CONFIG_FILE /var/task/collector.yaml

# EDIT: Added this line
ENV AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER /opt/otel-instrument

# ENTRYPOINT /lambda-entrypoint.sh dummy_lambda.lambda_handler
CMD ["dummy_lambda.lambda_handler"]
```

`dummy_lambda.py`:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("In lambda_handler!")
```

`collector.yaml`: is [the default one](https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-lambda/blob/main/adot/collector/config.yaml), except I’ve changed `awsxray` to `logging`  to print the traces to the console.

Output from Docker container:

```
15 Jan 2024 10:51:34,993 [INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)
START RequestId: 7110132c-c8e1-4570-84da-b0e9da4c3ad8 Version: $LATEST
15 Jan 2024 10:51:37,182 [INFO] (rapid) INIT START(type: on-demand, phase: init)
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.1941624,"msg":"Launching OpenTelemetry Lambda extension","version":"v0.35.0"}
15 Jan 2024 10:51:37,194 [INFO] (rapid) External agent collector (e37669fd-0163-4851-966b-ff3185aa729a) registered, subscribed to [INVOKE SHUTDOWN]
15 Jan 2024 10:51:37,195 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime without AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN , Expected?: false
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.1955585,"logger":"telemetryAPI.Listener","msg":"Listening for requests","address":"sandbox.localdomain:53612"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.1958878,"logger":"telemetryAPI.Client","msg":"Subscribing","baseURL":"http://127.0.0.1:9001/2022-07-01/telemetry"}
{"level":"error","ts":1705315897.1970472,"logger":"telemetryAPI.Client","msg":"Subscription failed. Logs API is not supported! Is this extension running in a local sandbox?","status_code":202}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.1971807,"logger":"telemetryAPI.Client","msg":"Subscription success","response":"{\"errorMessage\":\"Telemetry API is not supported\",\"errorType\":\"Telemetry.NotSupported\"}\n"}
2024/01/15 10:51:37 attn: users of the prometheusremotewrite exporter please refer to https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector/issues/2043 in regards to an ADOT Collector v0.31.0 breaking change
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.1975057,"logger":"NewCollector","msg":"Using config URI from environment","uri":"/var/task/collector.yaml"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.2109199,"caller":"service@v0.90.1/telemetry.go:86","msg":"Setting up own telemetry..."}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.2117138,"caller":"service@v0.90.1/telemetry.go:203","msg":"Serving Prometheus metrics","address":"localhost:8888","level":"Basic"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.211973,"caller":"exporter@v0.90.1/exporter.go:275","msg":"Deprecated component. Will be removed in future releases.","kind":"exporter","data_type":"metrics","name":"logging"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.2340708,"caller":"exporter@v0.90.1/exporter.go:275","msg":"Deprecated component. Will be removed in future releases.","kind":"exporter","data_type":"traces","name":"logging"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.2350507,"caller":"service@v0.90.1/service.go:148","msg":"Starting aws-otel-lambda...","Version":"v0.35.0","NumCPU":2}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.2351215,"caller":"extensions/extensions.go:34","msg":"Starting extensions..."}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.2354815,"caller":"otlpreceiver@v0.90.1/otlp.go:83","msg":"Starting GRPC server","kind":"receiver","name":"otlp","data_type":"metrics","endpoint":"localhost:4317"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.2358475,"caller":"otlpreceiver@v0.90.1/otlp.go:101","msg":"Starting HTTP server","kind":"receiver","name":"otlp","data_type":"metrics","endpoint":"localhost:4318"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705315897.236114,"caller":"service@v0.90.1/service.go:174","msg":"Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data."}
{"level":"error","ts":1705315897.2362807,"logger":"telemetryAPI.Listener","msg":"Unexpected stop on HTTP Server","error":"listen tcp: lookup sandbox.localdomain on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host"}
15 Jan 2024 10:51:37,261 [INFO] (rapid) INIT RTDONE(status: success)
15 Jan 2024 10:51:37,261 [INFO] (rapid) INIT REPORT(durationMs: 79.798000)
15 Jan 2024 10:51:37,262 [INFO] (rapid) INVOKE START(requestId: 924b0e64-64c1-4178-ac26-cf3a3ea4dcd9)
In lambda_handler!
15 Jan 2024 10:51:37,263 [INFO] (rapid) INVOKE RTDONE(status: success, produced bytes: 0, duration: 0.774000ms)
15 Jan 2024 10:56:37,237 [WARNING] (rapid) AwaitAgentsReady() = errResetReceived
15 Jan 2024 10:56:37,237 [ERROR] (rapid) Invoke failed error=errResetReceived InvokeID=924b0e64-64c1-4178-ac26-cf3a3ea4dcd9
15 Jan 2024 10:56:37,237 [WARNING] (rapid) Reset initiated: Timeout
15 Jan 2024 10:56:39,237 [WARNING] (rapid) Deadline: the agent extension-collector-1 did not exit after deadline 2024-01-15 10:56:39.23705518 +0000 UTC m=+304.243664413; Killing it.
15 Jan 2024 10:56:39,237 [INFO] (rapid) Sending SIGKILL to extension-collector-1(13).
END RequestId: 924b0e64-64c1-4178-ac26-cf3a3ea4dcd9
REPORT RequestId: 924b0e64-64c1-4178-ac26-cf3a3ea4dcd9  Init Duration: 0.05 ms  Duration: 300000.00 ms  Billed Duration: 300000 ms      Memory Size: 3008 MBMax Memory Used: 3008 MB
```

---

**EDIT**: After adding `ENV AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER /opt/otel-instrument` to my Dockerfile, the output of my container is different and has the output shown below. It looks like it's exporting the spans (maybe?), but it's still not terminating everything.

```
23 Jan 2024 17:02:48,419 [INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)
START RequestId: fd930622-f6b5-407f-bdb7-3c3ea705b60d Version: $LATEST
23 Jan 2024 17:02:51,689 [INFO] (rapid) INIT START(type: on-demand, phase: init)
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7013865,"msg":"Launching OpenTelemetry Lambda extension","version":"v0.35.0"}
23 Jan 2024 17:02:51,702 [INFO] (rapid) External agent collector (6ff72d84-10f8-475a-98f9-2be8a18cf246) registered, subscribed to [INVOKE SHUTDOWN]
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7024112,"logger":"telemetryAPI.Listener","msg":"Listening for requests","address":"sandbox.localdomain:53612"}
23 Jan 2024 17:02:51,702 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime without AWS_SESSION_TOKEN , Expected?: false
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7028499,"logger":"telemetryAPI.Client","msg":"Subscribing","baseURL":"http://127.0.0.1:9001/2022-07-01/telemetry"}
{"level":"error","ts":1706029371.7052574,"logger":"telemetryAPI.Client","msg":"Subscription failed. Logs API is not supported! Is this extension running in a local sandbox?","status_code":202}
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7055035,"logger":"telemetryAPI.Client","msg":"Subscription success","response":"{\"errorMessage\":\"Telemetry API is not supported\",\"errorType\":\"Telemetry.NotSupported\"}\n"}
2024/01/23 17:02:51 attn: users of the prometheusremotewrite exporter please refer to https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector/issues/2043 in regards to an ADOT Collector v0.31.0 breaking change
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7059617,"logger":"NewCollector","msg":"Using config URI from environment","uri":"/var/task/collector.yaml"}
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7127142,"caller":"service@v0.90.1/telemetry.go:86","msg":"Setting up own telemetry..."}
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7138865,"caller":"service@v0.90.1/telemetry.go:203","msg":"Serving Prometheus metrics","address":":8888","level":"Basic"}
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.714231,"caller":"exporter@v0.90.1/exporter.go:275","msg":"Deprecated component. Will be removed in future releases.","kind":"exporter","data_type":"traces","name":"logging"}
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7155623,"caller":"service@v0.90.1/service.go:148","msg":"Starting aws-otel-lambda...","Version":"v0.35.0","NumCPU":2}
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.715847,"caller":"extensions/extensions.go:34","msg":"Starting extensions..."}
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7161446,"caller":"otlpreceiver@v0.90.1/otlp.go:83","msg":"Starting GRPC server","kind":"receiver","name":"otlp","data_type":"traces","endpoint":"localhost:4317"}
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7175572,"caller":"otlpreceiver@v0.90.1/otlp.go:101","msg":"Starting HTTP server","kind":"receiver","name":"otlp","data_type":"traces","endpoint":"localhost:4318"}
{"level":"info","ts":1706029371.7177145,"caller":"service@v0.90.1/service.go:174","msg":"Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data."}
{"level":"error","ts":1706029371.790157,"logger":"telemetryAPI.Listener","msg":"Unexpected stop on HTTP Server","error":"listen tcp: lookup sandbox.localdomain on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"}
23 Jan 2024 17:02:52,703 [INFO] (rapid) INIT RTDONE(status: success)
23 Jan 2024 17:02:52,703 [INFO] (rapid) INIT REPORT(durationMs: 1013.435000)
23 Jan 2024 17:02:52,703 [INFO] (rapid) INVOKE START(requestId: 3ea8be1b-f113-4803-8242-d99f78025147)
In lambda_handler!
{"level":"info","ts":1706029372.7185798,"msg":"TracesExporter","kind":"exporter","data_type":"traces","name":"logging","resource spans":1,"spans":2}
23 Jan 2024 17:02:52,719 [INFO] (rapid) INVOKE RTDONE(status: success, produced bytes: 0, duration: 16.667000ms)
```

Comment: `AwaitAgentsReady() = errResetReceived`: it looks like registered layer didn't report ready state. Did you try to add env variable `AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER: /opt/otel-instrument`?

Comment: Yes I have added that to no avail. Let me retry and edit the question to include that.

Comment: Actually @JanGaraj , adding that environment variable to my Dockerfile changed the output. I've added it to the post.

Comment: Why you are expecting that Lambda is terminated after execution? Usually, it is active and still ready to serve other invocations - it is "idling" and it is ready for hot invocations, not cold start. Idling is managed by AWS - https://www.pluralsight.com/resources/blog/cloud/how-long-does-aws-lambda-keep-your-idle-functions-around-before-a-cold-start So I believe ADOT collector from the OTEL layer is still running and that's expected behaviour.

Comment: @JanGaraj Usually I'll see some lines like this that the Lambda function's invocation completed succesfully:
```END RequestId: ...

REPORT RequestId: ... Duration: 122.20 ms Billed Duration: 1002 ms```.

After 5 minutes, I'll see more logs that indicate that the Lambda timed out. My Postman request won't receive a response.

Comment: Your Lambda handler doesn't have any return value. Why you just don't return simple `return {"statusCode":200,"body":{"message":"ok"}}` (or some similar dummy valid response)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but it doesn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the [collector configuration (`collector.yaml`)](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda#custom-configuration-for-the-adot-collector-on-lambda) is set up correctly for a local environment. Some settings might be optimized for AWS Lambda's cloud environment and might not work well locally.

Increase the logging level of the [ADOT Collector](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/collector) to gain more insights into what is keeping it running. There might be some processes or threads within the collector that are not terminating as expected.

You could try and implement a mechanism to gracefully shut down the ADOT Collector once the Lambda function has completed its execution. That might involve adding custom logic in your Lambda function to signal the collector to shut down.
That could also resolve issues like [`aws-observability/aws-otel-lambda` #508](https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-lambda/issues/508): "Fail gracefully when the Lambda Telemetry API isn't available"

You might need to modify your `Dockerfile` and `dummy_lambda.py`. For instance:

`Dockerfile`:

```
# existing contents 

# Add a script for starting the Lambda function and ADOT collector
COPY ./start_lambda_and_collector.sh /var/task/start_lambda_and_collector.sh
RUN chmod +x /var/task/start_lambda_and_collector.sh

CMD ["/var/task/start_lambda_and_collector.sh"]
```

`start_lambda_and_collector.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Start the Lambda function in the background
/lambda-entrypoint.sh dummy_lambda.lambda_handler &

# Save the PID
LAMBDA_PID=$!

# Wait for the Lambda function to finish
wait $LAMBDA_PID

# Now gracefully shut down the collector
# (Add commands here as necessary)
```

#### Updated Lambda Handler (`dummy_lambda.py`)

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("In lambda_handler!")
    # Add any necessary logic for graceful shutdown signaling
```

That solution assumes you have a way to signal the collector to shut down. If the ADOT collector does not provide an easy way to do this, you might need to explore additional scripts or configurations.

---

> I don't see any clear way of sending a shutdown signal to the collector.

Then you would need an alternative approach to disable OpenTelemetry locally.
A possible solution would be to modify your setup so that OpenTelemetry and its collector are only initialized and run when your Lambda function is deployed in AWS, *not* when you are running it locally.

Define an environment variable in your Lambda's configuration in AWS to indicate that it is running in the cloud.
For example, you could set `IS_AWS_ENVIRONMENT` to `true`.

Then modify `dummy_lambda.py` to initialize OpenTelemetry only if it detects that it is running in AWS.

```py
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if os.getenv('IS_AWS_ENVIRONMENT') == 'true':
        # Initialize OpenTelemetry here
        pass

    print("In lambda_handler!")
    # Rest of your Lambda code
```

When you run the container locally, do *not* set the `IS_AWS_ENVIRONMENT` variable, or set it to `false`. That will bypass the OpenTelemetry initialization.

No changes are required to `Dockerfile` and `collector.yaml`: the OpenTelemetry setup remains as is, but it will not be initialized when running locally.

However, by disabling OpenTelemetry locally, you will not be able to test its integration or its impact on your Lambda function's behavior during local development. You will need to rely on AWS deployments for testing OpenTelemetry-related functionality.

Comment: I don't see any clear way of sending a shutdown signal to the collector. I appreciate your effort and your answer. I don't understand this technology well enough to solve this problem, I guess. I think my solution for now will be to somehow make OpenTelemetry not run locally.

Comment: @JoshClark OK I see: I have edited the answer to provide an alternative approach.